QT 5.15.2 QDate::DaysTo returns 0 despite all variable types being correct
I am looking to find files in a folder and check how old they are.
I have this piece of code that is not working as I expect it to per documentation and examples I have followed:
const QDate today = QDate::currentDate();
Q_FOREACH(auto fileInfo, QDir("folderName").entryInfoList(QDir::Files)) {
    
    // These variables are added to the watch table to see their values
    auto test1 = fileInfo.created().date().daysTo(today);
    auto test2 = fileInfo.baseName();
    auto test3 = fileInfo.suffix();
}

I add the test1, test2, test3 variables to the watch table to see what values they have.
It seems to me that daysTo(today) returns 0 because today is an invalid format. It is in julian day. But it is of type QDate and QDate::daysTo(QDate d) wants a QDate type variable as a parameter. This seems correct to me?
And the correct files are found as well, having checked with basename and suffix. And they are not 0 days old... Rather a month or so old.
Why is daysTo returning 0 despite everything seeming ok?
I am using QT 5.15.2.
Update: I have added some more tests and changed the created() function to birthTime(). See comments for the results I find when watching the variables in the watchtable:
    const QDate today = QDate::currentDate();
    Q_FOREACH(auto fileInfo, QDir("folderName").entryInfoList(QDir::Files)) {

        auto test1 = fileInfo.birthTime().date().daysTo(today);         // Gives "0"
        auto test11 = fileInfo.birthTime();                             // Gives "msecs=280348"
        bool test111 = test31.isValid();                                // Gives "true"
        auto test12 = fileInfo.birthTime().date();                      // Gives "Julian day=2460417"
        auto test13 = fileInfo.fileTime(QFileDevice::FileBirthTime);    // Gives "msecs=280311"
        auto test2 = fileInfo.baseName();                               // Gives "filename"
        auto test3 = fileInfo.suffix();                                 // Gives ".jpg"


Attach a debugger to your code and jump into the daysTo method call to find out what happens.

QFileInfo does not have a created() method

@Fareanor QFileInfo used to have a created() method, but it's depracated: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo-obsolete.html. It was still available in Qt 5 to keep old code working. OP should use birthTime() instead.

Hmm ok, I have switched the created() to be birthTime() instead but it yields the same results.
I have also tried splitting up the series of functions @ test1 variable. What I find is that regardless of using created() or birthTime(), it will return todays date, as if it takes the date of the file variable being created rather than the real file iself...

@wohlstad Oh sorry, my bad, I didn't know that, I could not find it in the online doc for Qt 5.12 :/

Maybe the time is not available ? I just read from the documentation: If the file birth time is not available, this function returns an invalid QDateTime.

It seems to return a valid QDateTime from what I see, when I step past the function it has data->status=176 and data->msecs=282896. So it seems to measure the msecs it has been alive or something. It does not look invalid at least. I don't know what status means either, both fields vary each execution.

Just out of interest, how do you know daysTo always returns 0 -- the code shown doesn't use the result test1 at all?  Please provide a [mcve] that can be used to demonstrate the problem.

I add the test1 variable to the watch table, I find I can get more info out of the variable that way rather than printing it or something similar. Same with the other variables.

I have found my solution now. There was nothing wrong with the code(except using the deprecated create() function) and the msecs field in the QDate variable was a red herring...
The issue was that the files resets their birthtime when they are copy-pasted to a new place. So they count as being created that day: today.
So even if the Operative System recognize the files as a month old, fileInfo.birthTime() or fileInfo.fileTime(QFileDevice::FileBirthTime) does not reflect this. I tried QFileDevice::FileMetadataChangeTime as well and that did not work either.
I noticed this once I checked seconds passed instead of days using secsTo() and QDateTime instead of daysTo() and QDate. Had I let the copied files remain untouched in the folder for a day I would have seen that they are 1 day old.

Well, the reasoning behind it is a bit obvious if you think about it: you're copying a file. Imagine somebody writing their journal in year 1042. Then somebody finds that journal in 1346 and thinks it's would be good to make a "book", so they make a copy of its contents rewritten by hand. The same happens in 1680, but with movable types. Somebody else does the same in 1912, to print a book based on the 1346 edition (identical to the 1680 one). In year 1999 another one rewrites it in plain text, and another one in 2024 as a PDF. When is the birth date of the PDF file?
